# Is there an issue with making a custom polling method for Selenium automation?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

First of all, here's the C# code (even though the question is language-independent):

```
public static void PollClick(IWebElement element, int timeout = defaultTimeout, int pollingInterval = defaultPollingInterval)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
        {
            try
            {
                element.Click();
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval);
            }
        }
    }
```

This one is for clicking an element, but I could easily replace the click command with something else (visibility check, send text, etc). I'm setting up automation for IE, Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. I've come across a few situations where a certain web driver has a bug or the web page misbehaves for a browser (an element remains obscured, a crash with no stack trace, and other strange issues). This method has been used sparingly (once or twice) as I already have made use of the existing waits available for Selenium and have even created wrapper functions around those waits (including one that waits until an exception is no longer being thrown). Is it a bad idea to have this method handy? It did pass code review but I'm just curious as to what else I could do for anomalous situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with executing such a strategy. In point of fact, the language bindings themselves do exactly that in the `WebDriverWait` construct. In C# (and other language bindings too, I believe) there is a generic version that is not specific to waiting on elements called `DefaultWait` which gives the user more control over things like what exceptions are caught and ignored, what timing interval to use, and so on. The caveat to repeating actions on the page like clicking elements is that there is a chance for the action to happen more than once, which may have unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is **no issue** at all in implementing a custom polling method as per your code.

But the question is **Why?**

The *Selenium Language Bindings* **Java, Python, C#, Ruby** internally implements the same and provides us the APIs to achieve the same. So adding one more layer to the existing layers will definitely will have an impact on the **performance** of your *Script Execution*.

Nevertheless, in general [as per this discussion](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-a-function-is-called-in-C++) when you creating a new function the usual costs of making the function call are :

- Push the variables onto the stack memory.
- Push the return address onto the stack memory.
- Branch-out to the destination function.
- Creating a new stack frame in the destination function.

Now, at the end of the function the undoing of all the above :

- Destroy the local objects created.
- Pop the return address.
- Destroy the pass-by-value parameters.
- Reset the stack pointer to where it was before the parameters were pushed to stack memory.

So, creating and calling an extra function stands pretty **costly** in terms of *System Resources*. To avoid that we can easily avail the services exposed by the *APIs* particularly the [**`ExpectedConditions Class`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as follows :

- [**`Presence`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy.htm) of elements : An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page that match the locator.
- [**`Visibility`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy.htm) of elements : An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is greater than 0.
- [**`Click/Interactibility`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) of element : An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

Comment: I've used the ExpectedConditions class in numerous places but they weren't enough in some cases where I was still getting exceptions thrown in certain browsers.

Comment: @DhruvKapoor As per the current implementation of ExpectedConditions it won't be wish to conclude they aren't enough until & unless we have a valid usecase as a reference. If you have any such usecase feel free to raise it as a question here. We will be glad to solve it for you.